# How do I get just the Facebook chat html into a web view?

Tags: html, facebook, chat

Okay so I was wondering how the Gabtastik chat client (site-specific-browser-esque) manages to present only the chat part of Facebook, as seen here: 
[image]

I'm making an app where I want to also include this functionality, but i really don't know how it is done, so i need a good kick in the right direction or some code or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just loads http://www.facebook.com/presence/popout.php. I found that out by running `strings` on the Gabtastik executable, like this:

```
strings /Volumes/Gabtastik/Gabtastik.app/Contents/MacOS/Gabtastik
```

Unfortunately, that doesn’t exist anymore. When you launch Gabtastik now, you see this:

[image: Alert: The page you requested was not found.]

Facebook has [XMPP access to chat](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) that you can use… unfortunately, integrating it into an app takes much more work than showing a web page.

Comment: Oh okay...
I know this is probably asking far to much. But by taking a quick look at Facebook.com itself do you see any alternative to the presence/popout.php?
I assume they didn't just scrap that functionality, but maybe changed/renamed it?

Comment: Do you think it would be possible for my app to have multiple arranged web views... and somehow each on isolated the chat parts of Facebook.com in order to present a ui similar to the pop out.php?

Comment: @mhuusko5 Unfortunately, it looks like it’s gone. [Here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/facebook-chat-only-page)’s someone else asking the same question. See the edit to my answer — it looks like the only option may be the XMPP chat API.

Comment: @mhuusko5 I’m not sure. Maybe someone else has another idea.